# Kik Bot setup config (confused)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bots, kik

I have the @kikinteractive/kik installed and the script test in the in the /home/usersite/node_modules/
This is where I get lost, on . Import `@kikinteractive/kik`
2. Create a bot with the username and API key you got from https://dev.kik.com/
3. Configure your bot as described in the [documentation][dev-config-kik-url]
4. Add the bot as middleware to your server with `bot.incoming()`
5. Start your web server,  where do I place the config/index for the kik bot? also where do I config this at? Can I get more detail on where the bot script folder will be placed and ran from, I was getting a node error trying to run the server.js from the kik starter bot script.

Comment: SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
when running the server.js with node command

Comment: What version of node are you running? I think you might have an old version, less than 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

First, if [quikst3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6041527/quikst3r) is correct, you'll want to first upgrade node and npm. Kik needs a minimum of node 5.4.0 and npm 3.3.12 as of this writing.

Second, once you're all good there, you need to send a POST request to kik containing the json with your config parameters in order to config your bot. I explain how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717073/how-to-set-kik-bot-webhook/37400166#37400166). Hope this helps.